# Separate Custom Post Type Taxonomy by Comma

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I tried to figure out how to separate the custom post type taxonomies.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , array( 'commitments', 'type' ) );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, array( 'commitments', 'type' ) );
        if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
        continue;
        echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
}
```

Each taxonomies show correctly. However, I cannot separate them in comma. it shows "TaxonomyATaxonomyB" but I want to show it as "TaxonomyA, TaxonomyB"

How to do it? or is there any other way around?

Thanks!

Comment: try this for the echo : `echo ', <a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';`

Comment: it shows , in the first line of the text. it shows ", TaxonomyA, TaxonomyB". It should have "Join"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a counter to determine if you need to add a comma or not :

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , array( 'commitments', 'type' ) );
// init counter
$i = 1;
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, array( 'commitments', 'type' ) );
        if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
        continue;
        echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        //  Add comma (except after the last theme)
        echo ($i < count($terms))? ", " : "";
        // Increment counter
        $i++;
}
```

Comment: This one works! thank you @Dexter0015 :) great help.

Answer (score 7):

Or you can use [get_the_term_list](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) function.

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'commitments', '', ', ' ); ?>
```

Comment: This one works too. short and neat :)

Comment: Only thing is I don't think you can pass multiple taxonomies to it

Comment: Awesome, simple and easy :)

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way (IMO) to do anything like this in PHP, is build an array and then implode it:

```
$list = [];
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term /* no need for taxonomy arg if $term is an object */ );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
        $list[] = $term_link;
}

echo implode( ', ', $list );
```

Comment: Far superior to using any type of count.